# How to fix "Error in try.xts(x, error = "'x' needs to be timeBased or xtsible") " in R?

Tags: r, time-series

I'm trying to run a time series analysis on a dataset from Twitter. I'm using the anomalize library. When running it on my data I get the following error, which seems to indicate an issue with the timestamp_r column:

```
Converting from tbl_df to tbl_time.
Auto-index message: index = timestamp_r
Error in try.xts(x, error = "'x' needs to be timeBased or xtsible") : 
  'x' needs to be timeBased or xtsible
```

Here's the code that produced the error:

```
combined_anom <- combined_dd %>%
  time_decompose(count) %>%
  anomalize(remainder, alpha = 0.05, max_anoms = 0.2) %>%
  time_recompose() %>%
  plot_anomalies(time_recomposed = TRUE) +
  ggtitle("Combined Brexit Dataset Anomalized")
```

And here's a glimpse of the dataset:

```
glimpse(combined_dd)
Observations: 186,128
Variables: 9
$ ID                 <int> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, …
$ X1                 <chr> "2", "72", "82", "96", "102", "103", "109", "115", "125", "127", "128", "137", "140…
$ text               <chr> "RT @ThatTimWalker: Can’t help but think the hostile environment the Brextremists a…
$ timestamp_datetime <chr> "2018-04-21 15:30:53", "2018-01-22 08:00:12", "2018-11-16 09:50:13", "2018-07-28 06…
$ tweet_id           <dbl> 9.877153e+17, 9.553494e+17, 1.063369e+18, 1.023093e+18, 9.863085e+17, 9.141128e+17,…
$ keyword            <chr> "brextremist", "brextremist", "brextremist", "brextremist", "brextremist", "brextre…
$ timestamp_r        <dttm> 2018-04-21 15:30:53, 2018-01-22 08:00:12, 2018-11-16 09:50:13, 2018-07-28 06:30:18…
$ date               <date> 2018-04-21, 2018-01-22, 2018-11-16, 2018-07-28, 2018-04-17, 2017-09-30, 2018-08-22…
$ day                <fct> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
```

I'm happy to provide anything else needed to reproduce the problem.

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Comment: Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: could you please, include a sample of the data that reproduces the problem using dput ? It's hard to rebuild data from a `glimpse` output and you don't say which of the calls in the pipe chain triggers the error. Please also  include your library calls.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I eventually figured out the issue by writing a reproducible example. I'm answering in the hope that this helps others (my first time answering a question!).

As noted in the [Anomalize Quick Start Guide](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/anomalize/vignettes/anomalize_quick_start_guide.html), the functions in the package must be performed on a tibbletime object (class tbl_time). In your case, the function is failing to convert your data object into tibbletime object. I suspect this is because of NA values in your datetime_r variable.

This generates the conversion error

```
library(tidyverse) 
library(anomalize)

# Create some test data
count <- c(1:25, 40, 27:50, 25, 52:75, 105, 77:100)
datetime_r <- seq(from = as.POSIXct('2013-01-01 00:00'), by = "1 hour", length.out = 100) 

# Insert an NA value into the datetime variable
datetime_r[25] <- NA

# Create a tibble object
test <- tibble(count, datetime_r)

# Run the amonalize function
test %>%
    # Data Manipulation / Anomaly Detection
    time_decompose(count) %>%
    anomalize(remainder, alpha = 0.05, max_anoms = 0.2) %>%
    time_recompose() %>%
    # Anomaly Visualization
    plot_anomalies(time_recomposed = TRUE) +
    labs(title = "Anomalies for Test Data")
```

The error message

```
Converting from tbl_df to tbl_time.
Auto-index message: index = datetime_r
Error in try.xts(x, error = "'x' needs to be timeBased or xtsible") : 
  'x' needs to be timeBased or xtsible
```

Remove the NA value from the datetime variable and re-run the function

```
count <- c(1:25, 40, 27:50, 25, 52:75, 105, 77:100)
datetime_r <- seq(from = as.POSIXct('2013-01-01 00:00'), by = "1 hour", length.out = 100) 

test <- tibble(y, datetime_r)

saved <- test %>%
    time_decompose(count) %>%
    anomalize(remainder, alpha = 0.05, max_anoms = 0.2) %>%
    time_recompose() %>%
    plot_anomalies(time_recomposed = TRUE) +
    labs(title = "Anomalies for Test Data")
```

No error generated this time.

This generates the following figure visualizing the anomalies identified by the function.

[Anomaly detection figure for test data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdRBZ.png)

Subset the saved data to examine the observations identified as anomalies.

```
saved$data[saved$data$anomaly == "Yes",]

# A time tibble: 4 x 10
# Index: datetime_r
  datetime_r          observed    season trend remainder remainder_l1 remainder_l2
  <dttm>                 <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
1 2013-01-02 01:00:00       40 -2.32e-15  26.0  1.40e+ 1    -1.58e-13     1.44e-13
2 2013-01-03 02:00:00       25 -7.79e-15  51.  -2.60e+ 1    -1.58e-13     1.44e-13
3 2013-01-04 03:00:00      105 -6.67e-15  76    2.90e+ 1    -1.58e-13     1.44e-13
4 2013-01-05 03:00:00      100 -6.67e-15 100.0  1.56e-13    -1.58e-13     1.44e-13
# ... with 3 more variables: anomaly <chr>, recomposed_l1 <dbl>, recomposed_l2 <dbl>
```